# Principal components selection and regression with LASSO? (I.e., Combining LASSO and Principal Components Regression)

Tags: regression, pca, lasso

Since conventional principal components regression can be prone to large prediction variance, is there a downside to using LASSO rather than OLS or truncating principal components with smallest singular values a priori? If some of these small singular-value components are important for prediction, then their removal a priori can lead to undesirable outcomes. As a side benefit, the feature selection advantage of LASSO can also bring interpretation through the selection of important principal components. (As we do not have response variables for all values in the data matrix, using PLS is not possible in this case - but we still want to use all samples to build the feature space.)

This application is different from sparse principal components analysis (no response variable here) or principal component-guided sparse regression (not necessarily looking for sparsity in the original variables). I have not seen anything similar in the literature but is there anything wrong with this approach? I believe this "PCA-LASSO" concept is mentioned in [this](https://bmcproc.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1753-6561-3-S7-S62) paper but the details are not entirely clear.

Comment: Can you clarify (and make a better title like " Combining Lasso and Principal component regression") Do you mean using ALL the PC's a predictors, then estimating with lasso?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Yes that's what I mean - I added that to the title but since there are other works combining LASSO and PCA in different ways (e.g., SCoTLASS, Principal Component-Guided Sparse Regression) I also wanted to keep it more specific about how I want to use LASSO with the principal components.